# I'm publishing image to fanpage but users aren't seeing the post (via api)

Tags: laravel, facebook, facebook-graph-api

My issue is simple. I have a problem with FB's API. When I'm trying to add an image as a post to my fanpage, it's fine. The problem is starting after that. Users aren't seeing the post. I'm (as admin) seeing a specified post.
I think this is a problem with app verification (but the app is still "live"). And questions now:
1. Is any solution to that problem? As via FB's API ofc,
2. Is any alternative? eg. other API which can publish posts to my fanpage

Comment: Are you *certain* the app is live?

Comment: Ya, I'm certain

Comment: And I noticed that when I switch app to "unlive" and "live" again, new posts are visible for users.